# Excel Pivot Table Multiple Date Columns Counted and Grouped By Month

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a table of data that has multiple date columns. I need to get a count of all date columns grouped by month. In the top Pivot, I do not get all months to show, even though I have expanded auto grouping to start at Jan and go to Dec for each rank.

I need a pivot like the bottom one showing all months (even if they have no data). And I need all months to show for all ranks.

And I DO NOT want the >date to show. I have date range turned off and it still shows.

Please help.

**Note: The numbers do not match up in the bottom as it is just text to show how I want the pivot to look.**

[image]

Comment: Use `COUNIFS()` function instead pivot table.

Comment: You may want to adjust the pivot fields settings to display items without data. If not sure where to find it, google will provide you with a decent amount of links for details.

Comment: @Anonymous I tried adjusting field settings. The problem arises when I have multiple column dates One column works fine.

Comment: @Harun24hr so you are saying the pivot table is the wrong way to go and I should just list out each month and have a countif for each month?

Comment: @WannabeCoder AFAIK the setting is for each column individually, you may want to check if can be set for all your date columns. Otherwise if the built-in pivot table feature does not match your requirements, you may try the proposal from @ Harun24hr to build your own table (which can become rather complex as well). About the line  “> date”: is it possible to filter out this entry with the related dropdown in the pivot table?

Comment: @Anonymous looks like I will go the route of building my own table. Thanks for your input.